# Syncing between SQLite and MySQL Android/iOS/Windows Ionic Framework

Tags: mysql, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, synchronization

I'm creating a Cordova ionic app for Android/iOS/Windows. I want to sync data between the SQLite and MySQL when user logins. There are around 15 master tables in MySQL which I need to sync with SQLite.

But for that I don't want to use Native Code like Background Services/Broadcast receivers for Android because I don't want use separate code for all three platforms otherwise it will be hectic to manage code for each platform. How can I sync data easily using AngularJS so that it won't affect app performance?